# HTACCESS - php > png

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting, png

I have a file `index.php`. It generates a picture with user's IP address, link looks like that:

```
http://www.example.com/addons/ip/index.php
```

And I want to change this to:

```
http://www.example.com/addons/ip/b1.png
```

Answer (score 0):

make your php code to generate it onto your server, calling it b1.png.

when your image is ready and saved on your disk, with user's ip address, change the location of your web browser with:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com/ip/b1.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Rewrite rule to your `.htaccess` file. File must be located at `addons/ip` path and contain next lines:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^b1.png$ index.php
</IfModule>
```

Also you need to enable `mod_rewrite` in your apache config to make it works.

Comment: Put here more information. Error messages for your log. You directory structure.

Comment: Structure: http://scr.hu/291m/smxuk
index.php: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MA1NcYa9

Comment: You need to find apache error log file. In that file will be described your problem with more details.